# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client /ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Tags: node.js, express

I try to make a request API for a post profile but for some reason the request had fail, I don't understand. So when I try it with the postman, first of all i sent an empty body request it return me the errors expected {"handle": "handle field is required",
"status": "status field is required",
"skills": "skills field is required"} , it work but when I resent the request again for example with just the handle field or two fields or all fields it throw me this kind of error: "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" instead of sending me errors or the response. So this is my code :

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
  const {isValid, errors} = validateProfileInput(req.body);

  // Check infos valid

  if(!isValid) {
    res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
  //Get fields
 const profileFields = {};
profileFields.user = req.user.id;

 if (req.body.handle) profileFields.handle = req.body.handle;
 if (req.body.company) profileFields.company = req.body.company;
 if (req.body.website) profileFields.website = req.body.website;
 if (req.body.location) profileFields.location = req.body.location;
 if (req.body.bio) profileFields.bio = req.body.bio;
 if (req.body.status) profileFields.status = req.body.status;
 if (req.body.githubusername) profileFields.githubusername = req.body.githubusername;

 //Skills - Split into array
 if (typeof req.body.skills) profileFields.skills = req.body.skills.split(',');

// Social
 profileFields.social = {};

 if (req.body.youtube) profileFields.social.youtube = req.body.youtube;
 if (req.body.facebook) profileFields.social.facebook = req.body.facebook;
 if (req.body.linkedin) profileFields.social.linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
 if (req.body.instagram) profileFields.social.instagram = req.body.instagram;
 
 Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id}).then(profile => {
  if (profile) {
    // Update
    Profile.findOneAndUpdate({user: req.user.id}, {$set: profileFields}, {new: true}).then(profile => res.json(profile))
  } else {
    // Create

    // Check if handle exists
      Profile.findOne({handle: profileFields.handle}).then(profile => {
        if (profile) {
          errors.handle = "That's handle already exists!"
          res.json(errors)
        }

        // Create new profile && save
        new Profile(profileFields).save()
        .then(profile => res.json(profile))
      })

  }
 })

})
```

Comment: This error was handled here a million times.

Comment: how to fix this kind of error?

Comment: Only send one response.

Comment: but in the tutorial the author try many times the request and it work fine